# Get contents of a clicked div

Tags: jquery

I have a string of divs with the same css class (.nav_div), with different text in each, in a navigation bar. They're set up like this:

```
<div class=nav_div>Contact</div>...
```

I set all those divs to enter a function when any is clicked, by this:

```
$('.nav_div').click(nav_is_clicked);
```

In the function `nav_is_clicked()`, I want to store the contents of the div that was clicked in a variable called `div_text`, but I'm having trouble. This did not work:

```
var div_text = $(this).contents().text();
```

How do I get the text from the div that was clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: `$(this).text()` or `.html()`

Comment: Make sure to read what `contents` and `text` do...

Comment: @A.Wolff, that's the correct answer.  You should probably create an answer so that this can be marked as answered.

Comment: @A.Wolff Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtMtS/

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) gives you "*the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.*", which is not what you want.

```
$('.nav_div').click(nav_is_clicked);

function nav_is_clicked() {
    var div_text = $(this).text();
}
```

**Edit -**

It looks like your original code does actually work: http://jsfiddle.net/SLVEs/

Are you binding the click handler before the element exists (like before the page is loaded)?

Comment: Yes, the original does work. Thank you so much. My mistake was in the alert statement I tried to display the contents using. That's what was wrong. Thanks for your help.